# When is a holomorphy ring a PID?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra, algebraic-curves, principal-ideal-domains, function-fields

I will use the notation and language of Stichtenoth, *Algebraic Function Fields and Codes*.

Let $F$ be a function field over a finite field $\mathbb F_q$, $S$ a non empty set of places (possibly infinite) and $O_S$ the holomorphy ring of $S$, i.e., $O_S:=\bigcap_{P\in S} O_P$ (being $O_P$ the valuation ring of the place $P$).

Give necessary and sufficient conditions for $O_S$ to be a Principal Ideal Domain.

Many thanks in advance!

G.